# How to generate C headers from Nim

Tags: c, header-files, nim-lang

I wrote a library which is intended to be used in C as well.
Compiling the library to a `.dll`/`.so`/`.lib` itself is well documented and works as expected.

However, I cannot find anything regarding the corresponding header files.
The only documentation for something like this that I found, is the [`--header` cli argument which was supposedly (to be?) removed](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/4738).
Can't find it in the https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html page, nor in the help-page of my installation.

Nim-Version:

```
$ nim -v
Nim Compiler Version 1.6.0 [Windows: amd64]
Compiled at 2021-10-19
```

In the documentation for the [`exportc` pragma](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#foreign-function-interface-exportc-pragma), it only explains the naming and how it can be used.
Same goes for the [backend-integration](https://nim-lang.org/docs/backends.html) Page, which also doesn't state anything helpful regarding header files.

Is there a proper way to generate the header-files from nim-source code, or do I have to write these manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Genny](https://github.com/treeform/genny) nimble package to generate a C header file (and also Python and Node.js bindings!) for your Nim library.

Besides that, writing the header manually would be the next best choice. Well, the `--header` option does still happen to work, but it's not recommended to use it as it's undocumented and unsupported.